# Multiple values JSON string Python (Django)

Tags: python, django, json

We have the following code working for receiving JSON strings for one value:

```
def spo2_new(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     data = {}
     fields = request.POST.copy()
     spo2 = SPO2(user=User.objects.get(pk=1), spo2=fields['value'], time=fields['datetime'])
     spo2.save()
     data['succes'] = True
    return JSONResponse(data)
raise Http404
```

The JSON string format POST is:

```
value=102.3&datetime=2011-05-04%2021:13:11
```

My question would be, how can we do the same for sending multiple "values" (with the datetime for each value) instead of sending each value individually?

Update 1: Since time interval is known, could I just send the values array and just the initial datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your page you can build an array and post those values manually as stated below:

```
values=[[datetime1, value1],[datetime2,value2]]
```

Or you could loop over all items and build the list:

```
$.each($('.datetime'), function(i, item){
    datetime_values.append($(item).value());
}
```

Within your view you can get a list of values passed as:

```
request.POST.getlist('datetime')
```

Comment: I think it has to be built manually since the server is an Arduino board sending the data to a web server (the client in this case and running Django). So the string would look something like this? -> values=[[2011-04-05%2021:04:05, 132.4],[2011-04-05%2021:04:21, 151],[2011-04-05$2021:04:35, 123]]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using JSON why don't simply send a JSON-encoded array of values [(timestamp, value)]?

POST: `values=[[datetime1, value1],[datetime2,value2],...]`